# Conditional return type and literal narrowing

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I just don't understand why this doesn't compile (TS 3.4.3). Could someone explain to me or correct my code? What am I missing here?

```
function run<A extends 'open'>(action: A): A extends 'open' ? 'yes' : never {
    if (action === 'open') {
        return 'yes'
    }
}
```

This example is boiled down to the not working part. It's meant to be a function which is called with certain Actions (A) and each one is supposed to have defined return values.

Action 'open' returns 'yes' or 'no'
Action 'send' return 'success' or 'fail'
etc.

Error I'm getting here:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'
>
> Type '"yes"' is not assignable to type 'A extends "open" ? "yes" : never'

Is that possible with Typescript at all?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does not now that `A` will be `'open'` even if you check the `action` parameter. The type guard will have no impact on `A` only on `action`. This means that typescript can't resolve the conditional type based on that type guard.

The simple work around would be to use a separate public signature with the conditional type, but have the implementation signature return a union.

Also `never` does not mean it returns nothing, it means it never returns, you are looking for `void`

```
function run<A extends 'open'>(action: A): A extends 'open' ? 'yes' : void
function run<A extends 'open'>(action: A): 'yes' | void 
{
    if (action === 'open') {
        return 'yes'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I will go with the two signatures. And I need to read on the differences between void, undefined and never... it's still confusing me 

Comment: `void` and `never` are two types specific to functions returning (`never` might be used in conditional typing but it's another subject), while `undefined` is for variables or parameters. `undefined` is just the javascript type. `void` is used for a functions that do not returns anything, while `never` is used for a function that does never returns (usually you use it when you function always throw an exception) - hope it clarifies it ;)